# Function which removes a given word from a string

Tags: c, strings

### Any improvements? Please review.

It could be faster if I use own `strstr` function which searches from the end (less memory to move) but I wanted to use only the standard functions.

```
char *removestr(char *str, const char *word)
{
    char *ptr = str;
    size_t len = strlen(word);
    while((ptr = strstr(ptr, word)))
    {
        if(isalnum(*(ptr + len)) || (str != ptr && isalnum(*(ptr -1))))
        {
            ptr += len;
        }
        else
        {
            memmove(ptr, ptr + len, strlen(ptr + len) + 1);
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Are you able to [edit] your post to include some example usages for this function?

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest renaming your variables. `str`, `ptr`, and `len` don't tell us much about what they're meant to be.

```
size_t len = strlen(word);
```

Since this is never going to change (because it's abstractly a property of a const input) you might as well mark it const.

```
while((ptr = strstr(ptr, word)))
```

I would put a comment here, not least as a note that the assignment is deliberate. (Because so often a single equals sign in an `if` or `while` implies  a bug). Really you could do with a few more comments throughout to say why you're doing things: For example the `if(isalnum...` could be commented to explain that you only want to remove whole words.

```
strlen(ptr + len)
```

This may work fine, but it's a moderately expensive thing to do because it has to run down the length of the remaining list. I would be inclined to measure the length `str` at the start outside the loop, and track it across updates.

```
memmove(ptr, ptr + len, strlen(ptr + len) + 1);
```

Again this works fine, but it has to copy (quite slowly and carefully) the whole remaining string. Because it's in a loop, this becomes an \$ O(n^2) \$ function. One solution would be to only move back the string up to the next time `word` appears. This would mean a bit more complexity tracking the size of the gap that you're building up, but it would reduce the overall complexity of the function to \$ O(n) \$.

Comment: I disagree with the need to comment the single `=` sign. That is what the extra set of braces inside the `while()` is doing. It is quite common (and considered good practice by most (not me personally)) to use assignment in both if and while in C. The extra braces are there to show this is an assignment that must be done before expression is evaluated for a condition.

Comment: I usually make that case more explicit (because double parens are easy to overlook) by doing `if/while ((x = foo(whatever)) != NULL)` so there's still a comparison that's obvious.

Comment: As well as the variables, the function could do with a better name (e.g. `remove_word()`).  I couldn't at first see why `isalnum()` was required.

Answer (score 2):

**Order of complexity higher than needed**

With `memmove()`, which execution time varies linearly with `strlen(str)`, inside a loop which iteration count can depend on `strlen(str)`, this algorithm is at least  \$ O(n^2) \$ and a  \$ O(n) \$  is possible.  Use separate pointers to read from `str` and write to `str` can accomplish \$ O(n) \$ - still in the forward direction.  See below.

**What if arguments overlap?**

`word` could exist at the end of `str`, and so `removestr(char *str, const char *word)` must account that `word[]` may change anytime `str[]` changes.  To inform the compiler this situation is not relevant employ `restrict`.

```
// char *removestr(char *str, const char *word)
char *removestr(char *restrict str, const char *restrict word)
```

This may improve performance a bit as it can allow various compiler optimizations

**Avoid UB**

`is...(x)` functions are UB when `x < 0 && x != EOF` as they are designed for `unsigned char` and `EOF`.  As a `char` may be negative, cast to `(unsigned char)` to cope with this pesky C nuance.

```
// isalnum(*(ptr + len)
isalnum((unsigned char) *(ptr + len))
```

---

Sample lightly tested \$ O(n) \$ code following OP's lead of `while((ptr = strstr(ptr, word)))`

(Really \$ O(strlen(str) *  strlen(word)\$ vs. OP's \$ O(strlen(str)^2 *  strlen(word)\$).

```
// Remove all "stand-alone" occurrences of `word` from `str`.
// For `word` to stand-alone", it must not be preceded nor followed by letter/digit
char *removestr(char * restrict str, const char *restrict word) {
  size_t w_len = strlen(word);
  if (w_len == 0) {
    return str;
  }
  const char *src = str;
  char *dest = str;
  char *token;

  while ((token = strstr(src, word)) != NULL) {
    // Copy sub-string
    while (src < token) { // Could alternatively use memmove() here
      *dest++ = *src++;
    }
    if (isalnum((unsigned char) src[w_len]) ||
        (src > str && isalnum((unsigned char) src[-1]))) {
      // `word` match is not "stand-alone"
      *dest++ = *src++;
    } else {
      // skip `word`
      src += w_len;
    }
  }
  // copy rest of `str`
  while ((*dest++ = *src++) != '\0');
  return str;
}
```

Tests

```
void removestr_test(const char *str, const char *word) {
  char *test_str = strdup(str);
  char *result = removestr(test_str, word);
  printf("%d <%s> <%s> --> <%s>\n", result == test_str, str, word, test_str);
}

int main(void) {
  removestr_test("", "the");
  removestr_test("the", "the");
  removestr_test("the beginning", "the");
  removestr_test("in the beginning", "the");
  removestr_test("end the", "the");
  removestr_test("thenot thenot notthe notthe", "the");
  removestr_test("xx the xx the xx the xx the xx the xx the", "the");
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
1 <> <the> --> <>
1 <the> <the> --> <>
1 <the beginning> <the> --> < beginning>
1 <in the beginning> <the> --> <in  beginning>
1 <end the> <the> --> <end >
1 <thenot thenot notthe notthe> <the> --> <thenot thenot notthe notthe>
1 <xx the xx the xx the xx the xx the xx the> <the> --> <xx  xx  xx  xx  xx  xx >
```